# 2nd order PDE with highest order term a mixed derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I stumbled upon an odd little pde (in the height $H$) here, and I don't really know where to begin the analysis.

\begin{equation}
0 = \frac{\partial^2 H }{\partial t \partial x } +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}H + f \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} + H
\end{equation}

where the prescribed function $f=f(x,t)$ is, unfortunately, time-dependent but otherwise can be taken to be sufficiently "nice".
I also know $H(x,0) \geq 0$ and decreasing in $x$, and my intuition for the physical system tells me $H(x,t)$ should be non-negative and decreasing in $x$ for all time.

Is there hope for my little pde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $y = x-t$ and $z=x+t$, which is equivalent to $x = (y+z)/2$ and $t = (z-y)/2$.  Then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial t}.
$$

In the new variables your problem becomes
$$
0 = \partial_z^2 H - \partial_y^2 H + H(\partial_z f +\partial_y f) + f(\partial_z H +\partial_y H ) +H,
$$
and this is a wave equation with lower-order terms.

Comment: That's great! But any clues as to how study this wave equation?